# How can I insert json data into mysql Using python?

Tags: mysql

Through postman, json data was answered.

How can I insert that json data into mysql?

The code below is the one I tried.

### my code

```
import pymysql
import requests
import json





def get_db():
    db = pymysql.connect(
        host='host',
        port=3306,
        user='admin',
        passwd='???',
        db='AIR',
        charset='utf8'
    )
    return db
     
    

    


# json data insert
def insert_json_data():
    
    db = get_db()
    mycursor = db.cursor()
    

    # -------------------postman query data -----------------------------
    url = "https://us-central1-mytypescript-62c14.cloudfunctions.net/getData"

    payload = json.dumps({
      "fromDate": "20210801180000",
      "toDate": "20210801190000",
      "siteCode": "unv_0001",
      "key": "Qkslffk@91",
      "serialNum": "24:0A:C4:22:37:72",
      "format": "json",
      "segment": "avg"
    })
    headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    
    
    mycursor.execute(response.text)
    #mycursor.execute("insert into 0804_AIR_JSON(SerialNum,Co2,Humid,Pm10,Pm5,Temp,Vocs,timeZone,ReportTime,Lat,Lng) value (%s ,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",(SerialNum,Co2,Humid,Pm10,Pm5,Temp,Vocs,timeZone,ReportTime,Lat,Lng))

    #db.commit()
    #db.close()

    print(response.text)



insert_json_data()
```

### response.text output

[{"serialNum":"24:0A:C4:22:37:72","co2":"474.6","humid":"52.4266666666667","pm10":"5.9","pm5":"5.9","temp":"30.29999999999997","vocs":"11.7","timeZone":"GMT+09:00","reportTime":"20210801180066.383","lat":"36.77289692333334","long":"126.93172890666672"},{"serialNum":"24:0A:C4:22:37:72","co2":"474.93333333333334","humid":"52.5483333333333","pm10":"6","pm5":"6","temp":"30.30999999999998","vocs":"11.733333333333333","timeZone":"GMT+09:00","reportTime":"20210801180166.9","lat":"36.77286716000003","long":"126.93173653333325"},{"serialNum":"24:0A:C4:22:37:72","co2":"480.3333333333333","humid":"52.68333333333331","pm10":"5.4","pm5":"5.183333333333334","temp":"30.345000000000013","vocs":"12.6","timeZone":"GMT+09:00","reportTime":"20210801180266.2","lat":"36.77285200000004","long":"126.93174199999994"},

It hasn't been resolved in three days.

### mygoals

> How can I insert that json data into mysql?

Comment: 1) Specify precise MySQL version. 2) Provide complete CREATE TABLE for a table which the data must be inserted into. 3) Provide final state of the destination table after the values of the shown *response.text output* are inserted.

Comment: parse the JSON into array and iterate the array insert into the mysql